# .Net NetworkCredentials insecure password stored as plain text when using SecureString

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developing a client application that consumes rest services using System.Net.Http.HttpClient with basic authentication. In order to provide the credentials I'm using the **System.Net.NetworkCredential** class.

From security perspective I'm trying to make my application as secure as possible, thus using **System.Security.SecureString** to hold the password. I stumpled upon a strange thing w.r.t. System.Net.NetworkCredential class. Whenever I set the SecurePassword property of the NetworkCredential instance and access the Password property, the **clear text** repesentation of the password is returned. This sounds for me a like a **security issue**. But honestly I'm not sure if the password is persisted as clear text in memory.

The following simple test method illustrates this behavior.

```
[TestMethod]
public void SecureNetworkCredentials_StoredAsPlainText()
{
    // Arrange
    String clearPassword = "mySecurePassword";
    SecureString encryptedPassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (var character in clearPassword.ToCharArray())
    {
        encryptedPassword.AppendChar(character);
    }
    // Act
    NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential();
    cred.SecurePassword = encryptedPassword;

    // Assert
    Assert.AreNotEqual(cred.Password, clearPassword, "The password should not be the cleartext");
}
```

Can anyone shed light on this behavior or provide a soltuion how to get rid of it?

Comment: The SecurePassword member of NetworkCredential is an instance of SecureString. All SecureString instances are encrypted when stored in memory. The point of SecureSting is to avoid the password from being stored in memory in clear text. But allow for you to get and set the value using the clear text values.

Comment: @Zeb. It is clear to me that the SecurePassword property is stored encrypted, but the NetworkCredential class has two properties SecurePassword of type SecureString and Password of type String. I was rather talking about the Password property. Especially your last sentence points to a possible solution. Does it mean that when accessing the Password property setter, the string value is encrypted before stored and for the getter it is decrypted on the fly and never kept in memory as clear text?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. From my understanding that is how it would work. The Password property returns a sting password, but there isnt's a string Password variable stored, the getter and setter would interact with the SecurePassword property.